# jquery .load() slows down after multiple loads

Tags: jquery

I wrote this fairly simple lightbox type function in jquery:

```
//LIGHTBOX FUNCTION
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.litebox').click(function(event) {

        if ($('.lightbox_bg').length > 0) {

            $('.lightbox_content').empty();
            $('.lightbox_bg').empty();


            var link = $(this).attr('href');

            $('.lightbox_bg').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.lightbox_content').fadeIn('slow');

            $('.lightbox_content').load(link);
            event.preventDefault();

        } else {

            $("body").append("<div class='lightbox_bg'></div>");
            $("body").append("<div class='lightbox_content'></div>");

            var link = $(this).attr('href');

            $('.lightbox_bg').fadeIn('slow');
            $('.lightbox_content').fadeIn('slow');

            $('.lightbox_content').load(link);
            event.preventDefault();

        }

    });

    $("a#close-panel").click(function() {

        $('.lightbox_content').fadeOut(300).empty();
        $('.lightbox_bg').fadeOut(300).empty();

    });

});
```

I added the .empty to try and empty the data of the div but if you open a link after the 4th time it slows way down and after the 6th or 7th time its almost crashing the browser.
I'm very new to this. How do I get rid of the old data or the div entirely so that it won't slow down. And I don't want to refresh the browser page. If I refresh it fixes the problem but  there must be a more elegant solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

thank you!

Craig

EDIT:

Ok so I simplified the code a little and added some Alerts to see what was happening. This is the new code.

```
//Lightbox Function

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.litebox_edit').click(function(event){

    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    if($('.lightbox_bg').length == 0){

        alert('No box'); 

        $("body").append("<div class='lightbox_bg'></div>");
        $("body").append("<div class='lightbox_content'></div>"); 

    }

        alert('box exists');

        $('div.lightbox_bg').fadeIn(300); 
        $('div.lightbox_content').fadeIn(300).load(link);


 event.preventDefault();

});



 $("a#close-panel").click(function(){ 

    $('div.lightbox_content').fadeOut(300);
    $('div.lightbox_bg').fadeOut(300);


}); 
});
```

So what happens is the first time you click on a link it says alert "no box" you click ok then it says alert "box exists" then It shows the lightbox.

Then you close the box. Now when you click the link again it says Box exists then you click ok and it then says "box exists" AGAIN and then shows the box.

Then the third time you click the link it will say "box exists" 3 or 4 times and that will keep increasing every time you close the box and reclick the link.

Changing the tags from .lightbox_bg to #lightbox_bg makes no difference .

Any ideas? I must be creating a loop somehow. But I don't know how.

Thank you.

Craig

Comment: Check ajax request using firebug. any recursion is happening

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your code, I would guess that what is slowing you down is your jQuery selectors. Doing a `.load()` call, once loaded, should remove all old content and replace it with the new content. All your jQuery selectors are doing global queries based on a class name - this is slow in general (even if not many elements are matched by your selector). As much as possible try to reference elements by ID (using `#` syntax) and if you want to select multiple elements, you can select based on a tag name and the class name like this:

```
$("div.lightbox_bg");
```

See if that helps. But the behavior you describe is strange, it shouldn't slow down *that* much each time, since you're only adding one div each time. Anyway let me know how you go.

Comment: I changed all the  '.lightbox_bg' to "#lightbox_bg" and I changed the '.lightbox_content' to "#lightbox_content" and the problem is still the same. By the 4th time opening a link it is chugging and by the 7th time it barley loads at all.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW,  I was having a similar problem when the returned AJAX snippet included script references to resources already referenced by the loaded page.   Once I ensured I didn't "re-reference" the scripts in the AJAX snippet the problem went away.